# Javascript Regular Expression: alternation and nesting

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is what i've got so far:

```js
/(netscape)|(navigator)\/(\d+)(\.(\d+))?/.test(UserAgentString.toLowerCase()) ? ' netscape'+RegExp.$3+RegExp.$4 : ''
```

I'm trying to do several different things here.

(1). I want to match *either* `netscape` or `navigator`, and it must be followed by a single slash and one or more digits.

(2). It can optionally follow those digits with up to one of: one period and one or more digits.

The expression should evaluate to an empty string if (1) is not true.

The expression should return `' netscape8'` if `UserAgentString` is `Netscape/8` or `Navigator/8`.

The expression should return `' netscape8.4'` if `UserAgentString` is `Navigator/8.4.2`.

The regex is not working. In particular (this is an edited down version for my testing, and it still doesn't work):

```js
// in Chrome this produces ["netscape", "netscape", undefined, undefined]
(/(netscape)|(navigator)\/(\d+)/.exec("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20060912 Netscape/8.1.2".toLowerCase()))
```

Why does the `8` not get matched? Is it supposed to show up in the third entry or the fourth?

There are a couple things that I want to figure out if they are supported. Notice how I have 5 sets of capture paren groups. group #5 `\d+` is contained *within* group #4: `\.(\d+)`. Is it possible to retrieve the matched groups?

Also, what happens if I specify a group like this? `/(\.\d+)*/` This matches any number of "dot-number" strings contatenated together (like in a version number). What's `RegExp.$1` supposed to match here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "or" expression is not doing what you think.

Simplified, you're doing this:

`(a)|(b)cde`

Which matches either `a` or `bcde`.

Put parentheses around your "or" expression: `((a)|(b))cde` and that will match either `acde` or `bcde`.

I find http://regexpal.com/ to be a very useful tool for quickly checking my regex syntax.

Comment: I think that's it. I was trying to reduce the number of parens because it pollutes the number of matches there are. I wish there could be non-match-grouping grouping operators. Thanks for that link also. Handy!

Comment: There are!  Javascript supports `(?:...)`, which groups the `...` but doesn't put it in a matched capturing group.

Comment: @AntalS-Z That's quite awesome. Hopefully I can remember that next time I write a massive JS regex.

Answer (score 1):

*Regex* `(netscape|navigator)\/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` *will return 2 groups (if match found):*

1. netscape or navigator
2. number behind the name

   ```
   var m = /(netscape|navigator)\/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/.exec(text); 
   if (m != null) { 
     var r = m[1] + m[2]; 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`(....)`  Creates a group.  Everything inside that group is returned with that group's variable.

The following will match `netscape` or `navigator` and the first two numbers of the version separated by a period.

```
          $1                       $2
 |------------------|        |------------|
/(netscape|navigator)[^\/]*\/((\d+)\.(\d+))/
```

The final code looks like this:

```
/(netscape|navigator)[^\/]*\/((\d+)\.(\d+))/.test(
     navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()
) ? 'netscape'+RegExp.$2 : ''
```

Which will give you

`netscape5.0`

Check out these great tuts (there are many more):

- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html